# Using CAT5 cable for multiple door contacts @ 24v per pair back to a Moxa unit

Tags: electrical, wiring

Working on a smart Moxa system that is monitoring Fire and Door access. Thinking of using a CAT5 cable to run to door contacts using 24v to monitor. Can I use the same cable for 4 doors, or best practice use a cable for each ?

Comment: What's a "Moxa system"? What do the instructions for the system install say to use?

Comment: It's a digital input monitoring unit. monitors switches, fire alarm outputs and enables monitoring across the internet.

Comment: Do the instructions indicate that CATx cable is safe to use? If so, run with it, otherwise, use the cabling spec'd in the instructions.

Comment: This is a commercial type of question not a home DIY.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not home improvement based.